# How to assign a value to variable while extending a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

it is possible to assign a value to a variable, in the command "extend"?

for example:

```
ele1=[]
ele2=[]
list=[ele1,ele2]
list[0].extend([a=1,b="bla"])
```

instead of:

```
ele1=[]
ele2=[]
list=[ele1,ele2]
a=1
b="bla"
list[0].extend([a,b])
```

Comment: No, you cannot. Why obfuscate your code to that extend?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. Code looks less crowded with a few spaces in there ala PEP8

Comment: thx... I'm missunsing my code as GUI (for now). ele1 and ele 2 are inputs. (for the user)it looks nicer to "name" the list and then populate it, than first populate it and then name it. hope you understand what I'm trying to say.. my english isnt the best :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python distinguishes between "expressions", which have a value and can be generally used wherever a value is needed, and "statements", which perform some action, do not have a value, and cannot be placed in a spot where a value is needed.

Assignment is a statement, and cannot be embedded as a value anywhere, including in a list literal.

(This often comes as surprise to people coming from C-like languages, which do make assignment an expression, but which can often lead to hard-to-find bugs when people, e.g., confuse `=` and `==` in conditionals.)

Answer (score 1):

No, Python doesn't allow assignment inside expressions (because it's a great source of bugs) but there are other ways to write your example without the repetition. eg.

```
a, b = ele1 = [1, "bla"]
ele2 = []
lst = [ele1, ele2]
```